# CMake: the right way to deal with static and shared libraries

Tags: linux, cmake, debian, debian-based, debian-packaging

Let's consider Debian or Ubuntu distro where one can install some library package, say `libfoobar`, and a corresponding `libfoobar-dev`. The first one contains shared library object. The later usually contains headers, static library variant and cmake exported targets (say, `FoobarTargets.cmake`) which allow CMake stuff like `find_package` to work flawlessly. To do so `FoobarTargets.cmake` have to contain both targets: for static and for shared variant.

From the other side, I've read many articles stating that I (as a libfoobar's author) should refrain from declaring `add_library(foobar SHARED ....)` and `add_library(foobar_static STATIC ...)` in `CMakeLists.txt` in favour of building and installing library using `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` and `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`. But this approach will export only one variant of the library into `FoobarTargets.cmake` because the later build will overwrite the first one.

So, the question is: how to do it the right way? So that package maintainer would not need to patch library's `CMakeLists.txt` to properly export both variants from the one side. And to adhere CMake's sense of a true way, removing duplicating targets which differ only by static/shared from the other side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote [an entire blog post](https://alexreinking.com/blog/building-a-dual-shared-and-static-library-with-cmake.html) about this. A working example is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/alexreinking/SharedStaticStarter).

The basic idea is that you need to write your `FoobarConfig.cmake` file in such a way that it loads one of `FoobarSharedTargets.cmake` or `FoobarStaticTargets.cmake` in a principled, user-controllable way, that's also tolerant to only one or the other being present. I advocate for the following strategy:

1. If the `find_package` call lists exactly one of `static` or `shared` among the required components, then load the corresponding set of targets.
2. If the variable `Foobar_SHARED_LIBS` is defined, then load the corresponding set of targets.
3. Otherwise, honor the setting of `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` for consistency with FetchContent users.

In all cases, your users will link to `Foobar::Foobar`.

Ultimately, you cannot have both static and shared imported in the same subdirectory while also providing a consistent build-tree (FetchContent) and install-tree (find-package) interface. But this is not a big deal since usually consumers want only one or the other, and it's totally illegal to link both to a single target.

Comment: OMG, it is just an hour since I wrote the question and you have found it with such a thorough answer ) I've started to read your post and I feel in advance that you've done a great job. I go and read your article to the end and I'll write back upon I complete the reading. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I've read your post. 10/10!